# css animation flickering in ie edge

Tags: css, css-animations

I've got a hover css animation to "fade out" text on a button (and scroll an icon across), this works across all the main browsers, except for IE Edge. In IE Edge the text flickers. I've tried different things to make it work, but no matter what I've tried, it still flickers on IE Edge. My code is:

```
#navbar ul li.item-122 a:hover{-webkit-animation:fadeOutText 0.5s;-moz-animation:fadeOutText 0.5s ease-in-out;-ms-animation:fadeOutText 0.5s ease-in-out;-o-animation:fadeOutText 0.5s ease-in-out;animation:fadeOutText 0.5s ease-in-out;-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden} /* the text to fade */

#navbar ul li.item-122 a:hover::before,#navbar ul li.item-122 span:hover::before{-webkit-animation:moveToRight 0.5s ease-in-out;-moz-animation:moveToRight 0.5s;-ms-animation:moveToRight 0.5s ease-in-out;-o-animation:moveToRight 0.5s ease-in-out;animation:moveToRight 0.5s ease-in-out} /* the icon moving - this works fine, it's the text which flickers */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutText{
    0%{color:#005baa}
    80%{color:#005baa}
    100%{color:#fff}
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeOutText{
    0%{color:#005baa}
    80%{color:#005baa}
    100%{color:#fff}
}
@-o-keyframes fadeOutText{
    0%{color:#005baa}
    80%{color:#005baa}
    100%{color:#fff}
}
@keyframes fadeOutText{
    0%{color:#005baa}
    80%{color:#005baa}
    100%{color:#fff}
}
```

If you need the icon moving css, let me know, but I don't think it has any impact on the flickering text??